# How to verify what code actually does in the hardware in a language like C++?

Tags: c++, hardware

P.S. I'm fairly new to programming.

Having used Javascript, I've been wanting to learn C++ since both of their syntax looks similar, and I'm quite intrigued about what code actually does in the hardware.

However, we can't actually look at hardware activity easily right?

I can only take a compiler's word for it that my array has been properly allocated only 5 indexes, but I can't see that visually in my ram or something else easily right?

How do I verify stuff like this at least a little better?

With JavaScript, it didn't bother me really, because I was mainly just writing much more non-countable things (or at least more abstract) of what I want to happen, so how can I feel more confident about C++ claiming that it actually gives me control over these tiny things?

Comment: You might want to inspect generated assembly code that's generated by your compiler compiling your program. [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) is a good place to start

Comment: A debugger may also help you with this.

Comment: On a modern PC system, C++ (or even C, and really also assembly) doesn't interact directly with hardware. Instead it invokes *system calls* which are the operating systems specific functions that work on a much lower level and communicates with the drivers that access the hardware directly. For a normal application there's quite a few layers between your program and the hardware.

Comment: As for trusting the compiler, [maybe you shouldn't](https://www.archive.ece.cmu.edu/~ganger/712.fall02/papers/p761-thompson.pdf)? ;) (In reality, you can trust the compiler. If you create an array of 5 elements, you will have memory for five elements.)

Comment: Re: " both of their syntax looks similar" -- unfortunately, that's probably right; however, their **semantics** are vastly different, so don't let this apparent similarity mislead you.

Comment: Depends on the platform.  In many embedded systems, we use tools such as Logic Analyzers and Oscilloscopes to show what the code is doing with the hardware.  These tools can also measure the efficiency of the instructions or programs.  However, some items may not be open or available to the tools, such as items internal to the processor or system on a chip (SOC).

Comment: A good project to learn about the fundamentals of Microcomputers, would be to build or purchase a board that has common components of a small processor and write your own firmware / microcode.  This would give you hands on to what actually goes on in the hardware.

Comment: I still have yet to figure out the Downvoters.  Could be lack of research before posting.  Could be multiple questions in one question.  See [mcve] for more information.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for is a debugger. Many IDEs provide one, and the one that comes with Visual Studios allows you to view memory, registers and CPU activity. If you want to do it manually, you can always rely on inline assembly, or by comparing the addresses of objects allocated on the stack or heap.

Answer (score 0):

> However, we can't actually look at hardware activity easily right?

The debugger is worth learning, and simple programs are easy to debug.  Remember that on most desktops, your debug code is running in virtual memory ... meaning that the addresses are probably not hardware addresses, they are virtual, and might be mapped to any physical ram.

---

> I can only take a compiler's word for it that my array has been properly
>   allocated only 5 indexes, but I can't see that visually in my ram or
>   something else easily right?

I'm not sure what you think 'properly' means.  How could it be improper as long as it behaves as you told it?  I mean no offense, but how would you or I recognize if something is improper?  alignment?  padding?  In my experience, the padding 'inserted' by the compiler (in any struct), is visible in the debugger displays.

Any memory you 'inspect' with the debugger is from virtual memory.  The addresses shown are the virtual ram addresses which **your** code is using.

---

> With JavaScript, it didn't bother me really, because
>   I was mainly just writing much more non-countable things (or at least
>   more abstract) of what I want to happen, so how can I feel more
>   confident about C++ claiming that it actually gives me control over
>   these tiny things?

With practice.

I have many years experience with C++ on embedded systems, mostly vxWorks.  Embedded systems often do have virtual memory.  Memory mapped i/o are typically accessed through special hardware, the OS is 'informed' of their special nature, and the hardware usually has different timing than 'regular' virtual ram.

---

> How do I verify stuff like this at least a little better?

Stuff like what?  I am not sure what you think you could see in Java.

What 'stuff' do you think you will not be able to see in C++?

---

**The debugger is worth learning**, and simple programs are easy to debug.

AND you are always allowed to 'throw in' some diagnostic cout's.  In this example I have implemented overloaded show functions.  (for development or diagnostics only ... probably you do not want to ship your code with show()'s enabled)

Example:

```
 DTB::SOps_t sops; // string operations 
                   //  digiComma() inserts comma's for readability

 void show(uint64_t ui64)
 {
    cout << "\n  " << setw(24) << sops.digiComma(ui64) << flush;
 } 

 void show (uint64_t sum1, uint64_t sum2, uint64_t digit, uint64_t digit2)
 {
    cout << "  "
         << setw(8) << sops.digiComma(sum1)
         << setw(8) << sops.digiComma(sum2)
         << setw(8) << sops.digiComma(digit)
         << setw(8) << sops.digiComma(digit2)
         << flush;
 }
```

---

show() Usage examples on a sample:

```
 int exec()
 {
    cout << "\n  Note that llui and uint64_t "
         << "\n  are the same size (on my Linux/g++ system) - 8 bytes"
         << "\n    sizeof(  llui ): " << sizeof(llui)
         << "\n    sizeof(uin64_t): " << sizeof(uint64_t) << endl;

    uint64_t checksum = 4024007185756128;  
    show(checksum);

    uint64_t   sum1 = 0;
    uint64_t digit1 = checksum % 10ULL;
    uint64_t   sum2 = 0;

    while (checksum > 0)
    {
       sum2 = sum2 + digit1;

       uint64_t digit2 = ((checksum - digit1) / 10ULL) % 10ULL;
       show(sum1, sum2, digit1, digit2);

       checksum = (checksum - digit1 - (digit2 * 10ULL)) / 100ULL;

       digit1 = checksum % 10ULL;
       digit2 =   digit2 * 2ULL;
       sum1   =     sum1 + digit2;

       show(checksum); 

       if (checksum < 10) { checksum = 0; }
    }

    if ((sum1 + sum2) % 10ULL == 0ULL)  cout << "\n  INVALID 1"; 
    else                                cout << "\n  INVALID 2"; 
    return 0;
 }
```

This output might be called 'trace' results of the executing code, about 15 lines.

---

When the above helps a little, you might next try running the debugger on this code. Just add a break point at the show routines. Then run, and inspect the results, continue to next breakpoint, inspect the results, repeat.

Comment: The code runs to completion, but I do not know if the result is correct ...